# One field always the same how should i store in that case

Tags: mysql, database

so i have a Documents table i want to store the history of documents:

---

```
Id |Doc_number| Date | Statue_Id | Type_id
```

---

The type_id can be 1(means export) or 2(means import).
So the question is when i want to store this:

```
insert into Documents values(

    (1,'AA10',10.03.2015,1,2),
    (2,'AA10',12.03.2015,2,2),
    (3,'AA10',15.03.2015,3,2));
```

Can I do this way or should I make two tables(becuse type_id was the same each time in that case):
Documents_export, Documents_import, without the type id?For example above the AA10 document has an import type

---

```
Id |Doc_number| Date | Statue_Id |
```

---

Comment: That entirely depends on your select usage. So will be better if you provide the usage specifically what information you want to select.

Comment: Thats fine to have `type_id` in the first approach.

Comment: i thought it is a fault to stroe a field multiple time which has the same value

Answer (score 0):

What is *Statue_Id* usage? it seems it differentiate your each row values.

but still I suggest for history, its better if you keep all values within single table so its okey here to store type_id every time so that by seeing history one can make sure that what action happens with particular document, how many times. which is general fundamental of keeping history of any item

Comment: statue_id means the state it can be for example : ordered,in commission etc

Answer (score 0):

The question on how data structures should be based on how the information is going to be used.  You do not provide that information, so any answer is speculation.

That said, you seem to be asking whether "import document" and "export document" are two separate entities.  Or, is "document" a single entity with an attribute to distinguish these types.

I would tend to think the latter, because the only distinguishing feature you have is the `type` column.  This suggests a single table with a type.  However, I could easily envision a system where these were different things.  Import documents might have sources, dates, and users associated with them.  Export documents might have formats, version, dates, destinations, and other information.  In that case, there would be a stronger case for splitting them into two separate tables.

Comment: However i want to story export and import documents in this table i only wants to store the state of it(ordered,in commission etc.)so in that case the only difference here is the type(1 or 2) as you wrote.